# How do you count degrees of freedom in multivariate distributions?

Tags: t-test, multivariate-analysis, degrees-of-freedom, multivariate-distribution

When dealing with a multivariate distribution (e.g., a multivariate t-distribution), how does dimensionality play into degrees of freedom? Let's say you have N measurements of a d-dimensional vector, assume that we have a well-behaved (non-singular) shape parameter matrix that we are estimating from the data,and we want to use a multivariate t-distribution to understand the uncertainty in our estimate of the mean. Is df simply N-1, as in the univariate case? Or is each component of each measurement and the mean a degree of freedom, leading to df = d*(N-1)? Or is there some more complicated calculation given that you are estimating d*(d+1)/2 independent entries of the covariance?

EDIT: it seems like the above is still ambiguous. Let me try and be more explicit:

I have a set of $N$ measurements $X = \{\mathbf{x}_1, \, ...,\, \mathbf{x}_N\}$ of a multivariate normally distributed $p$-vector with true mean $\mathbf{\mu}$ and true covariance $\Sigma$, both unknown and with no informative prior. I can use the sample mean as an estimator for the true mean, $\hat{\boldsymbol{\mu}} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i \mathbf{x}_i$. I want to know the distribution of the random variable $\boldsymbol{\delta} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\mu}} - \boldsymbol{\mu}$, the error from the true mean. At the risk of being pedantic, by distribution, I mean the probability density of $\boldsymbol{\delta}$ were I to resample another $N$ vectors from the same original normal distribution many times.

I brought up multivariate $t$-distributions because from my understanding, this distribution ought to be a multivariate $t$-distribution in the form

\begin{equation}
p(\boldsymbol{\delta}| X) = \frac{\Gamma[(\nu + p)/2]}{\Gamma(\nu/2) \nu^{p/2} \pi^{p/2} (\det S)^{1/2}}\left[ 1 + \frac{1}{\nu}\boldsymbol{\delta}^T S^{-1} \boldsymbol{\delta} \right]^{-(\nu+p)/2},
\end{equation}

where $\nu$ is the "degrees of freedom" and $S$ is a shape parameter matrix that is proportional to the sample covariance $\hat\Sigma$ with proportionality depending on $\nu$ (expressible alternatively in terms of $N$).

At this point, I have answered my original question by finding a result (In "Bayesian Data Analysis", 3rd Edition, Gelman, bottom of pg. 73) that corroborates my simulated data: that $\nu = N-p$, and that $S = \frac{1}{N(N-p)} \sum_i (\mathbf{x}_i - \hat{\boldsymbol{\mu}})(\mathbf{x}_i - \hat{\boldsymbol{\mu}})^T= \frac{N-1}{N(N-p)}\hat\Sigma$.

So even though I have solved my specific research problem at this point, I'm trying to understand why $\nu = N - p$. My (admittedly sophomoric) understanding of degrees of freedom is that they reflect the number of unconstrained random variables contributing to the shape of a distribution. But if we're talking about $N$ measurements of a $p$-vector, that's $N\cdot p$ random variables. Specifying the mean (also a $p$-vector) applies $p$ constraints. So thinking of each component of each vector as a random variable leads to a final count of $\nu = N p - p = p(N-1)$. Alternatively, thinking of each $p$-vector as a single random variable leads to the simpler $\nu = N-1$, the result typically used in calculating the sample covariance as an estimator for the covariance.

Neither of these results is $N-p$, which seems to require some hybrid philosophy where each vector observation is somehow just one degree of freedom, while specifying the mean constrains $p$ degrees of freedom. But $N-p$ is clearly empirically correct if you go and simulate data and assess its distribution.

So my question is: whence comes this result $\nu = N-p$? What is the logic? And as a corollary, why is $N-1$ always used as the degrees of freedom in the estimation of sample covariances (the classic formula being $\hat\Sigma = \frac{1}{N-1} \sum_i (\mathbf{x}_i - \hat{\boldsymbol{\mu}})(\mathbf{x}_i - \hat{\boldsymbol{\mu}})^T$), instead of $N-p$? Why does the shape parameter we plug into the $t$-distribution use a different denominator than $\hat\Sigma/N$?

Comment: D.f. of what? If your observations are i.i.d., your dataset has d.f.=N, loosely speaking. (Though again, that becomes meaningful only when we define what the d.f. refers to.) When you start manipulating it and deriving quantities from it, you may start losing degrees of freedom.

Comment: I mean the degrees of freedom used in the multivariate t-distribution describing the uncertainty in the mean of the N measurements. I've edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: Consider a single component of your vector: that tells you the answer.

Comment: Sorry, how is that?

Comment: In the absence of details, I am supposing your multivariate t distribution arises by dividing Normally distributed variates (like the vector of estimates) by the square root of an independent chi-squared variable *that is the same for all components.* The df is the df of that denominator.  But since there are many different distributions called "multivariate t," it would help for you to specify which one you have in mind and how specifically you plan to employ it.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my original question to add substantially more detail. Please let me know if there is still something missing.

Answer (score 0):

breaking it down in simpler terms, Imagine you have a bunch of measurements for a vector with different components, and you want to figure out the degrees of freedom for a multivariate t-distribution. Now, in the univariate case, it's easy—just N-1 degrees of freedom. But in the multivariate case it is a  bit different from the usual way.

So, for N measurements of a vector with d components, your degrees of freedom are usually N - d. It's like the exqample as follows, "I have this many measurements, but considering the dimensionality of my vector, I need to adjust my degrees of freedom accordingly."

Now estimating a covariance matrix for those measurements. If you're dealing with a full covariance matrix with d dimensions, you're estimating some of the parameters. This means you might have to do a bit more math to figure out the exact degrees of freedom, taking into account the number of parameters you're dealing with.

It's like trying to find a balance between the number of measurements, the dimensions of your vector, and the parameters you're estimating. If you're estimating a covariance matrix with d dimensions, you might have d*(d+1)/2 parameters to estimate (considering the symmetric nature of the covariance matrix). In such cases, the degrees of freedom could be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Could you provide any more precise details about calculating the degrees of freedom for the multivariate case? I understand that it varies depending on the dimensionality of the space and the number of measurements, but I'm trying to understand exactly how to calculate the correct number (and ideally, why the answer is what it is).

Comment: You seem to be invoking some kind of ordinary least squares regression setting, but it is unclear what it might be.